# Multiple wall collisions in python

Tags: python, pygame, pacman

I am creating a piece of code that involves a maze and doors that open when a button is hit. The problem is that when I put in the doors the player collision detects the doors but no longer detects the maze. I have put all my code down on here in hopes that if people can see any other problems they can help Thanks :)

```
import pygame, sys, random, time


#Setting up the colours
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
blue = (0,0,255)
green = (0,255,0)
red = (255,0,0)
orange = (248,100,1)
slateG = (112,128,144)
pink = (255,20,147)
dTurq = (0,206,209)
honeyD = (240,255,240)
maroon = (128,0,0)
goldenrod = (218,165,32)
sGreen = (0,255,127)
Fus = (255,0,255)


class player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    change_x=0
    change_y=0

    #initialise the class
    def __init__(self,x,y):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #the player will be 13x13
        self.image = pygame.Surface([13,13])
        self.image.fill(maroon)

        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = y
        self.rect.left = x

    def changespeed(self,x,y): #this function changes the speed of the player
        self.change_x+=x
        self.change_y+=y

    def updateWall(self,walls): #This is a collision detection function
        old_x=self.rect.left
        new_x = old_x+self.change_x
        self.rect.left = new_x

        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,walls,False)
        if collide:
            self.rect.left = old_x

        old_y = self.rect.top
        new_y = old_y+self.change_y
        self.rect.top = new_y

        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,walls,False)
        if collide:
            self.rect.top = old_y

    def updateBarrier1(self,barriers):
        gx=self.rect.left
        nx = gx+self.change_x
        self.rect.left = nx

        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,barriers,False)
        if collide:
            self.rect.left = gx

        gy = self.rect.top
        ny = gy+self.change_y
        self.rect.top = ny

        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,barriers,False)
        if collide:
            self.rect.top = gy






class Wall(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color): #this sets up for the x/y coordinates, the width and the height and the colour of the wall

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        #how big will the wall be
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])
        #what colour will the wall be
        self.image.fill(color)

        #initialising the x/y coordinates
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = y
        self.rect.left = x

class Bar(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)

        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height])

        self.image.fill(color)


        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.top = y
        self.rect.left = x


class Button(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
    def __init__(self,x,y,width,height,color):

        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.image = pygame.Surface([width,height]) #the buttons dimensions
        self.image.fill(color) #colour of the button

        #x/y coordinates
        self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
        self.rect.top=y
        self.rect.left=x

#Setting up the walls for the maze
def maze1():
    wall_list = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
    #Walls of maze
    walls = [[0,0,20,390,goldenrod],[0,410,20,390,goldenrod],[0,0,1000,20,goldenrod],
             [980,0,20,800,goldenrod],[0,780,980,20,goldenrod],[20,40,940,10,dTurq],
             [950,40,10,350,dTurq],[950,410,10,350,dTurq],[40,750,370,10,dTurq],
             [430,570,10,210,dTurq],[430,570,240,10,dTurq],[660,570,10,210,dTurq],
             [690,550,10,210,dTurq],[690,750,260,10,dTurq],[400,550,10,210,dTurq],
             [40,410,10,350,dTurq],[20,100,30,10,dTurq], [40,100,10,290,dTurq],
             [50,410,460,10,green],[50,380,350,10,green],[430,380,100,10,green],
             [530,380,10,100,green],[500,410,10,100,green],[500,510,60,10,green],
             [550,510,10,30,green],[580,510,10,30,green],[400,540,160,10,dTurq],
             [580,540,120,10,dTurq],[530,480,150,10,green],[680,430,10,60,green],
             [580,510,130,10,green],[710,460,10,60,green],[680,430,250,10,green],
             [710,460,190,10,green],[920,430,10,300,green],[890,460,10,230,green],
             [820,720,100,10,green],[820,690,80,10,green],[810,690,10,40,green],
             [550,410,400,10,sGreen],[550,210,10,200,sGreen],[250,210,300,10,sGreen],
             [250,210,10,120,sGreen],[250,330,180,10,sGreen],[430,330,10,50,sGreen],
             [580,380,370,10,sGreen],[580,180,10,200,sGreen],[220,180,360,10,sGreen],
             [220,180,10,180,sGreen],[220,360,180,10,sGreen],[390,360,10,20,sGreen]]

    for item in walls:
        wall = Wall(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4])
        wall_list.add(wall)
    return wall_list


def BarrierWhite():
    barriers = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
    barrier = [[500,540,10,40,white],[400,180,10,40,white]]

    for item in barrier:
        barrie = Bar(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4])
        barriers.add(barrie)
    return barriers



def BarrierPink():
    wall_list = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
    walls = [[550,520,40,10,pink],[20,600,30,10,pink],[300,380,10,40,pink]]

    for item in walls:
        wall = Wall(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4])
        wall_list.add(wall)

    return wall_list


def Buttons(): #Creating buttons
    buttons = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
    button1 = [[965,765,10,10,white]]
    for item in button1:
        button = Button(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4])
        buttons.add(button)

    return buttons

def pinkButton():
    pinkB = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
    b = [[835,705,10,10,pink]]
    for item in b:
        button = Button(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4])
        pinkB.add(button)
    return pinkB

#main line
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode([1000,800])

background = pygame.Surface(window.get_size())
background = background.convert()
background.fill(black)

player = player(25,25)
movingsprt = pygame.sprite.RenderPlain()
movingsprt.add(player)

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

wall_list = maze1()
barriers = BarrierWhite()

buttons = Buttons()
B1 = pinkButton()

done = False


while done == False:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

            #This makes the player move
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(-6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0,-6)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0,6)

        #This stops the player from moving
        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                player.changespeed(6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                player.changespeed(-6,0)
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                player.changespeed(0,6)
            if event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
                player.changespeed(0,-6)

    player.updateWall(wall_list)
    player.updateBarrier1(barriers)



    window.fill(black)

    movingsprt.draw(window)
    barriers.draw(window)
    wall_list.draw(window)
    buttons.draw(window)
    B1.draw(window)


    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(40)

pygame.quit()
```

Also if someone could tell me how to put a countdown timer that will disable the player and display a game over sign that would be awesome too :D

Comment: It's better to only post the relevant part of the code. People on Stackoverflow are really helpful but it's hard to take 20 minutes just to read a couple hundred lines of code.

Comment: Tip: instead of `Wall(item[0],item[1],item[2],item[3],item[4])`, you can write `Wall(*item)`, and Python will supply the elements of `item` as arguments to `Wall`. Also, your code would be more readable if it followed [PEP 8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) conventions for spacing and capitalization.

Comment: Is there any difference at all between `updateWall` and `updateBarrier1`?

Comment: I'm sorry but I am an amateur programmer and no there is no difference they're the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding doors (or `barriers` as you call them in your code) makes the wall collision ineffective because of a design problem in your game.

Here's what you do in your main loop:

```
player.updateWall(wall_list)
player.updateBarrier1(barriers)
```

You first check with collisions for a wall, then check again for collisions with barriers.
The problem is that you incorporated the part that makes your character move in those `updateWall` and `updateBarrier1` methods.

So for instance, if your character collides with a wall, but not with a door, the character will still move because the `updateBarrier1` method will not detect a collision with a barrier (door) and will make him move.

Instead, you should do some methods called `collides_wall` and `collides_barrier` that return `True` or `False` and then replace the two previously quoted lines by:

```
if not player.collides_wall(wall_list) and not player.collides_barriers(barriers):
    player.move()
```

With `move` a method that would move your player as you currently do in the `updateSomething` methods.

**Note:** Someone pointed out in the comments that you also don't need two separate methods for walls and barriers collision, because ultimately they are both sprites and you do exactly the same operations on both of them. So just add a `collides` method.

Comment: So if I put in a collide piece of code such as 
`def collide(self):
        old_x = self.rect.left
        new_x = old_x+self.change_x
        old_y = self.rect.left
        new_y = old_y + self.change_x
        collide = pygame.sprite.spritecollide(self,False)`
and then create a collides_wall and collides_barrier function that should work?

Comment: Nope, what you'd usually do is: 1) Move the character. 2) Check if there's a collision with walls OR with doors in his new position => if there's a collision, you move him back to where he was. Otherwise you continue. So you need a ``move(dx, dy)`` method, for instance, and a ``collides(stuff)`` method (as it's the same tests for both walls and doors, so better factorize.